# Kann man eigentlich sagen "ein Monat sind"?

Tags: grammaticality

Guten Tag!

Ich lese grerade Achtsam Morden am Rande der Welt von Karsten Dusse. Sehr lustig!

Der Herausgeber ist Heyne. Ich nehme an, Heyne hat sehr gute Lektoren.

Gestern waren zwei Sätze kurz aufeinander:

1. Ein Monat sind gut vier Wochen. (ein Monat sind??)
2. Eine Folge Bidi und Tina waren knapp 30 Minuten. (eine Folge waren??)

Was geschieht hier?

Comment: "Ein Monat sind gut vier Wochen. "

Vom [DWDS][1] "sind" vom Verb "sein"
Verb · ist, war, ist gewesen

Entweder

"1. Wirklich existieren"
"umgangssprachlich ⟨etw. ist⟩etw. gibt es, etw. ist vorhanden"

Oder

"4. gibt eine Klassifizierung an"
wieder im umgangssprachlichem Gebrauch


  [1]: https://www.dwds.de/wb/sein#3
  [2]: https://www.dwds.de/wb/sein#1

Comment: @Trae Bitte nicht in Kommentaren antworten. In der Frage geht es vermutlich um **sind** vs. **ist** bzw. um **waren** vs. **war**. Das sollte OP vielleicht präzisieren.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bei Verwendung des Gleichsetzungsnominativs steht das Verb im Plural, sobald eines der gleichgesetzten Nomen im Plural steht.

An

> Ein Monat sind gut vier Wochen.

ist deshalb nichts auszusetzen. Zwei Zeitspannen werden gleichgesetzt und *Wochen* steht im Plural.

Beim zweiten Beispiel

> Eine Folge Bidi und Tina waren knapp 30 Minuten.

stellt sich die Frage, ob das nicht mindestens fragwürdiger Stil ist. Hier geht es ja nicht darum, zwei Zeitspannen gleichzusetzen. Statt dessen wird die Dauer einer Folge angegeben. Jedenfalls sieht es so aus, solange der Satz isoliert steht. Dann sollte es doch besser heißen:

> Eine Folge Bidi und Tina **dauerte** knapp 30 Minuten.

Im Kontext mag das anders sein. Wenn es zum Beispiel heißt:

> Ich habe damals viel Zeit damit verbracht, mir Kindersendungen anzusehen. Eine Folge Bidi und Tina waren knapp 30 Minuten.

dann finde ich die Gleichsetzung wieder akzeptabel und dann gilt auch wieder die Regel, dass das Verb im Plural steht, weil *Minuten* im Plural steht.

Comment: Das kann nicht ganz stimmen Es heißt nicht »Ich *sind* zwei Tanks« sondern »Ich *bin* zwei Tanks«: https://www.willi-tank.de/s/cc_images/cache_2477753893.jpg?t=1517409694

Comment: @HubertSchölnast *Ich bin zwei Tanks* ergibt überhaupt keinen Sinn. Mit absurden Beispielen kannst du jede Regel sprengen. Hilfreich für jemanden, der Deutsch lernen will, sind sie aber nicht.

Comment: Die Absurdität dieses Beispiels stelle ich zwar heftig in Abrede. Immerhin standen diese Tanks zu Hunderten oder Tausenden in den 1970er-Jahren mit genau dieser Aufschrift als Werbeträger der Firma Haase im ganzen deutschen Sprachraum herum.

Comment: Das ist aber trotzdem gelebtes Deutsch: [Ich bin zwei Berliner](https://genius.com/Ufo361-ich-bin-2-berliner-lyrics) - [Ich bin zwei Scheren](https://www.sbz-monteur.de/produkte/ich-bin-zwei-scheren) - [Ich bin zwei Kameras](https://www.ict-channel.com/markt/pentax-ich-bin-zwei-kameras.52495.html) - [Ich bin zwei Teile](https://www.amazon.de/Ich-bin-zwei-Teile/dp/B01MPY94ZX) - [Ich bin zwei Baustellen](https://www.falter.at/zeitung/20120816/ich-bin-zwei-baustellen/1733230082) - [Ich bin zwei Bier](https://open.spotify.com/track/23CZlf0fGpIUa5KqCTwQ2e)

Comment: [Ich bin zwei Welten](https://www.yumpu.com/de/document/view/23770892/konzertbeschreibung-ich-bin-zwei-welten-karlsruher-) - [Ich bin zwei Affen](https://www.tagesspiegel.de/gesellschaft/medien/ich-bin-zwei-affen/727180.html) - [Ich bin zwei Personen](https://www.kn-online.de/Nachrichten/Hamburg/Caren-Miosga-Ich-bin-zwei-Personen) - [Ich bin zwei Autos](https://www.spiegel.de/fotostrecke/skoda-roomster-ich-bin-zwei-autos-fotostrecke-15397.html) - [Ich bin zwei Brücken](https://www.german-architects.com/de/architecture-news/reviews/ich-bin-zwei-brucken)

Comment: Geht auch mit mehr als zwei: [Ich bin drei Autos](https://www.autoplenum.de/auto/bilder/tests/bmw-m5-im-test-ich-bin-drei-autos-id15272) und natürlich [Ich bin viele](https://www.amazon.de/Ich-viele-Eine-ungewöhnliche-Heilungsgeschichte/dp/3498008951)

Comment: 1. vs. 3. Person: Nur *das sind zwei Tanks* (nicht *ist*).

Comment: @HubertSchölnast Ja. Und bei 11880 werden Sie geholfen. Das lief schließlich tausendfach im Fernsehen. Da behaupte noch mal jemand, *helfen* erfordere den Dativ.

Comment: Na dann, vielen Dank! Ich bin nun ein Stückchen schlauer!

Comment: "Eine Folge" ist auch eine Zeitspanne.

Comment: @vonbrand Nö. Eine arithmetische Folge beispielsweise hat mit Zeit überhaupt nichts zu tun. Selbst im Sinne von Fernsehfolgen steht überhaupt nicht fest, welche Zeitspanne so eine Folge umfasst.